# How to create .appxupload for created appx using makeappx tool?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

I have created appx for .Net Desktop application using makeappx tool.I had used this command to generate appx:
makeappx pack -d "C:\Centennial\PackageLayout"-p "C:\Centennial\Output\HelloCentennial.appx"
The package creation is succeeded and I am getting output as HelloCentennial.appx.The windows app certification kit test also passed.
But When I want to upload it on windows store it asks for .appxupload file.
I know .appxupload  is a zip-file contaning the .appx package and an .appxsym file.But I don't know how to manually create it or generate it using MakeAppx tool.It would be great If anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't know how to manually create it or generate it using MakeAppx tool

The .appxsym file cannot be created by MakeAppx.exe. You could use [PDBCopy.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-pdbcopy) to manually copy all PDB files related to all dll, exe or winmd libraries without private symbols. This tool takes a symbol file that contains both private symbol data and a public symbol table, and creates a copy of that file that contains only the public symbol table.

These PDB symbols can be zipped into .appxsym file. Then you can zip the .appx and .appxsym into the .appxupload file you need to upload.

There will be no crash analytic or debugging information available if you don't include the .appxsym.

Comment: Thanks for input,Mattew. I can use PDBCopy.exe to copy all PDB files related to all dll, exe or winmd libraries into one folder.Then after zipping that folder whether I need to renamed zip folder  to .appxsym ? Similarly for .appx and .appxsym, I can copy both of them into one folder and zip it,then whether I need to rename the zip folder to .appxupload?

Comment: Yes, you need to rename the zip folder after zipping the two files into one folder.